# Putty prevent text overflow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty, digital-ocean

I am using putty to connect with SSH, I have a problem I can't copy any output I get from commands because the the text keeps overflowing to the right of the window. Like this:

[overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiuQm.jpg)

Is there any way to make the text wrap to the next line when it reaches the edge of the window?

Comment: Disable auto wrap in the terminal settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're viewing system logs through the `less` [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) – a text viewer which handles all wrapping and scrolling independently from the terminal, PuTTY or otherwise. (The inverse `>` is distinctive of Less.)

While using Less, you can input **`-S` <kbd>Enter</kbd>** to switch line-wrapping on or off. (Normally Less will wrap lines by default, but certain tools such as systemctl or journalctl tell it to chop off long lines instead.)

Alternatively, use systemctl or journalctl with the `--no-pager` option to have them output log messages directly to terminal, without using a pager – then you *will* be using PuTTY's scrolling and wrapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked :)